# VB.NET & MYSQL - Select Different fields

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm currently working on a project of Voting System. I have a mysql database named "dbName" and 
fields

```
`for table "pospresident"
---------------|-------------|---------------- \n
  idCandidate  |  NumOfVote  |  CandidateName  \n
---------------|-------------|---------------- \n
    1          |    20       |      Joe
    2          |    30       |      Carlo
---------------+-------------+----------------

for table "posvpres"

---------------|-------------|----------------
  idCandidate  |  NumOfVote  |  CandidateName 
---------------|-------------|----------------
    1          |    15       |      Anne
    2          |    35       |      Lucas
---------------+-------------+----------------

and so on ...

`
```

I just want to display all the names of candidate in different table who get the highest number of votes. I just need an idea on how my SELECT query should be.

Comment: What are your desired results?  SUM of all tables or highest record in each table?

Comment: Oh, sorry haven't included that one. After the voting session ended, i will print the results ( all the candidate who got highest vote per table ) Individual per position.

Comment: No problem -- see my post -- you'd have to run it for each table or add a UNION and a type to show all in a single result set.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get the data from the two tables, then use `GROUP BY` with `SUM` and `HAVING` to get only this candidate that has the `MAX` votes. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  idCandidate,
  CandidateName,
  SUM(NumOfVote) Votes
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM  pospresident p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM posvpres v 
) AS t
GROUP BY idCandidate, CandidateName
HAVING SUM(NumOfVote) = (SELECT MAX(NumOfVote) 
                         FROM
                         (
                             SELECT  NumOfVote FROM posvpres
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT  NumOfVote FROM pospresident 
                         ) t);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3c82/3)

This will give you:

```
| IDCANDIDATE | CANDIDATENAME | VOTES |
---------------------------------------
|           2 |         Lucas |    35 |
```

Comment: Not by getting SUM of all the number of votes, I need to display the name of the candidate who got the highest number of votes in position ( for president, vice presidnet , secretary .. etc ). Well thanks for your response @mahmoud // oops didn't see you edited you post.

Comment: @ArvinVerdadIlustre - See my updated answer, it will get you the `CandidateName` as well as the `IDCANDIDATE`.

Comment: This is what i looking for the SELECT MAX(NumOfVote)

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud, Keep it up.

Comment: @ArvinVerdadIlustre You're welcome any time :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to select from each table individually.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT idCandidate, 
   CandidateName 
FROM pospresident 
WHERE NumOfVote = (SELECT MAX(NumOfVote) FROM pospresident)
```

And using the fiddle provided by Mahmoud: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3c82/4

Good luck.